# How to solve the problem of E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout for this coding?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am struggling to resolve 'No adapter attached; skipping layout' error. Here is my Password Manager activity:

```java
package com.example.passwordmanager;
    
// My imports:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
 
public class PasswordManager extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter adapter;

    // Start to set view:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_manager);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.listOfPass);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   }
}
```

The error is:

```
2022-03-18 12:11:31.937 8858-8858/com.example.passwordmanager E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize adapter and its better to create custom adapter which extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>